# How to remove the baseline in the Raman spectrum without falsifying the spectral data. Measurement of anisotropy using SERS?

Tags: computational-physics, software, data-analysis, raman-spectroscopy

My goal is to study the anisotropy of the sample based on changes in the Raman spectrum as a function of angle. The sample was rotated around the Z-axis and changes in the spectra are visible in the raw data.

The sample was rotated every 10 degrees resulting in a total of 18 spectra.

The important parameters for me are the intensity/width/position of each peak for each angle. The baseline subtraction process has a significant effect on the intensity values and a moderate effect on the peak width.

It is obvious that when subtracting the baseline the absolute values of intensity change, but when studying anisotropy the relative changes between measurements for successive angles are important.

For each spectrum, the subtracted baseline will vary, and I am concerned that (especially for peaks close together) the subtracted baseline may disturb the relative differences between intensities in measurements for successive angles.

I process my data in Wire 3.3 software provided by Renishaw and subtract baselines using cubic spline interpolation.

I would appreciate any advice on how to prepare the data for curve fitting without falsifying the resulting measurement data.